# Gitlab Mirror fail to create a branch <branch name> invalid reference name <commit sha>

Tags: github, gitlab, mirroring

We have GitHub repositories mirrored to Gitlab. At some point we experienced this error on pull mirroring:

```
Error: Failed to create branch 'foo/bar/feature-xy': invalid reference name '<commit_sha>'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happened because the Gitlab repository already has a branch called `foo/bar`, so now Gitlab doesn't allow any new additions that start with `foo/bar/*`.

In our case, we deleted the branch from Gitlab since, in GitHub, the same branch was already gone, and for some reason, Gitlab doesn't sync.